# How to delete service Association Link for Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers in Azure

Tags: postgresql, azure, associations, subnet

How can I delete an Azure subnet after it has been associated to `Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers`? When I try to delete the subnet is says:

```
Failed to delete subnet 'db-subnet'. 
Error: Subnet db-subnet is in use by application-vnet/db-subnet/db-subnet-service-association-link and cannot be deleted. 
In order to delete the subnet, delete all the resources within the subnet.   
See aka.ms/deletesubnet.`
```

When I try to delete the service association link it gives me not authorized error:

```
Azure Error: UnauthorizedClientApplication
Message: Unauthorized client application id xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.
```

I tried from bash, powershell, REST API and nothing. It does not matter if the PostgreSQL flexible server is present or deleted it gives me the same error and not I am stuck with two subnets that cannot be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's a known issue, and it takes an Azure support request to delete it.
(Or, possibly, you can recreate the server it was used for, disconnect it, and then delete it.)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/140197/unable-to-delete-vnet-due-to-serviceassociationlin.html
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/169500/unable-to-delete-virtual-network-and-a-resource-gr.html
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/48902
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f3fa0fb2-d930-484c-90a5-6860e360d87f/unable-to-delete-vnet-due-to-serviceassociationlinksappservicelink?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork